# link_to_remote: how do I abort the action, if a javascript variable is false?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I tried doing this:

```
<%= link_to_remote '',  {:url => {  :action=> :edit_content,
        :id=>content.id, 
        :controller=>@contents_controller}, 
        :before=>"false;",
        :complete => "click_content_after();"}, 
    :class=>'edit' %>
```

but the link still executes... the before block has no influence on the behavior of the link.

there is a :confirm option, but I don't want there to ALWAYS be a dialog... as I have js variables that watch the state of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize browser side call logic by passing in JavaScript code snippets `:condition` optional parameter and not `:before`. Read [link_to_remote API documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/link_to_remote).

I tested it in my old Rails 2.3.2 application and this works as expected. When `:condition => "true"` the call to remote is performed and not when `:condition => "false"`.

```
<%= link_to_remote "Temp", :update => "temp_update", :url => { :action => "temp" }, 
  :condition => "false", :complete => "alert('complete!');" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `:condition` parameter (e.g. `:condition=>"return false;"`) that should be evaluated before making the remote call, and will prevent the remote call if it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

`link_to_remote` will abort only if `:complete` returns `false`.